# Ignore none in list and take min and max values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have a list and need to apply function over it.

```
values =[1,3,5,None]

max(values)
```

and i receive this error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

but the expected output is

```
5
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `max(values, key=lambda x:0 if x is None else x)`? This obviously won't work for negatives.

Comment: it doesnt work for min().. It solves this problem though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```
max([v for v in values if v is not None])
```

Comment: but this takes another loop and reduces performance.. Any other best way..

Comment: Or other libraries which does this as simple as max function..

Comment: @MadanRaj if you are worried about space, use `max(v for v in values if v is not None)` this is based on generator.

Comment: Using filter is best i think.. Which gives more performance.. Is that fine..

Comment: @MadanRaj Do you **know** filter is faster?

Comment: Just found for loop is faster than filter. Thank you.. Answer accepted..

Answer (score 0):

You can use max function and remove None from list by simply using math module and iterate over a list and check if i is not equal to None. and append it to the new list.

Code ->

```
values =[1,3,5,None]
newlist = []
for i in values:
  if i != None:
    newlist.append(i)

max(newlist)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using the `math` module for?

Comment: @MadanRaj Yes we can use filter and Lambda function --> max(filter(lambda t: t is not None, values))

Comment: Explanation --> 1.filter takes two arguments, first: a function, second: original list
2. Whenever filter runs, all the elements present in the list are passed one by one in the function which returns true or false based on the condition specified in it
3. If it returns true, then the elements is kept in the filtered list, else it is not kept
4. Here, instead of creating a separate function, we used a lambda function

Comment: @Axe319 Sorry we will get the same output without import math. By mistake I imported math module.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filter() function to remove None from the list.

```py
max(list(filter(None,values)))`
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is wrong. Try with `[-2,-1,0]`. `0` will be filtered out and `-1` will become the max and that is not correct.

Comment: @MadanRaj Negative values are not the problem, but the zero is. `filter(None, ...)` removes everything boolean false, not only `None`.